# non-static method cannot be referenced and void type not allowed

Tags: java, swing

When I type `t.schedule(umm.setVisible(false), 5);` I get that error and void type not allowed.  Can someone clear this up for me?

```
public class menu extends JFrame{
JLabel bgmenu=new JLabel();
JLabel java=new JLabel();
JLabel umm=new JLabel();
JLayeredPane jLayeredPane1=new JLayeredPane();

public menu(){

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //label
    umm.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("D:\\Job\\Kuliah\\4\\DAMG\\Game\\pic\\umm.jpg")); 
    umm.setBounds(0, 0, 1024, 709);
    java.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("D:\\Job\\Kuliah\\4\\DAMG\\Game\\pic\\java.jpg"));
    java.setBounds(0, 0, 1024, 709);
    bgmenu.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("D:\\Job\\Kuliah\\4\\DAMG\\Game\\pic\\interfacemainmenu.jpg"));
    bgmenu.setBounds(0, 0, 1024, 709);

    //posisi
    jLayeredPane1.add(umm, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    jLayeredPane1.add(java, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    jLayeredPane1.add(bgmenu, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jLayeredPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1024, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jLayeredPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 709, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
    );

    pack();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new menu().setVisible(true);
    Timer t=new Timer();
    //get error here under this comment
    t.schedule(umm.setVisible(false), 5);
}
```

Comment: recheck signature of `schedule` method and look at `setVisible` return type.

Comment: Also consider [`javax.swing.Timer` v. `java.util.Timer`](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/timer/).

Comment: @carl-manaster thx, its clear now :)

Answer (score 1):

The first arg to Timer.schedule() should be a TimerTask. You are passing void (i.e. the result of umm.setVisible())

You need to wrap the setVisible() into a TimerTask's run() method.

Just typed this out, not tested, so some details could be suspect, but I think it's close to what you need. I'm sure there are plenty of "real" examples out there...

```
class MyTimer extends TimerTask
{
    private menu theMenu = null;
    public MyTimer(Menu m)
    {
        this.theMenu = m;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        // you need to add 
        // public void setUmmVisibility(boolean s)
        // { this.umm.setVisible(s); }
        // to the menu class.
        this.theMenu.setUmmVisibility(false);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    menu m = new menu();
    m.setVisible(true);
    Timer t=new Timer();
    t.schedule(new MyTimer(m, 5);
}
```

Comment: thx for ur reply, i already tried ur advice, but "non-static" error still show up

Comment: umm is a member of the class menu(). main() is a static member, so it cannot access umm. I'll edit the code to show you a way around it.